# Why does hm(7.4) and hm(7.04) both return 7H 4M 0S using lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I'm stumped as to what is happening here.  I'm using the lubridate package in the tidyverse and converting doubles to posix.  I keep getting the same result whether I input hm(7.4) or hm(7.04)

```
library(lubridate)

hm(7.4)
hm(7.04)
```

Here is what I get.

```
> hm(7.4)
[1] "7H 4M 0S"
> hm(7.04)
[1] "7H 4M 0S"
```

I'm not sure why `<hm(7.4>`  is not returning `[1] "7H 40M 0S"` which is what I'm expecting.

Comment: What led you to believe `hm(7.4) == 7H 40M 0S`? Was it stated in some documentation? It's definitely interesting though. Incidentally, `hm(7.40) == 7H 4M 0S` but `hm("7.40") == 7H 40M 0S`. My guess is the devs had to make a decision to privilege .4 == 4 due to the 'catch all' nature of `lubridate`. To illustrate, see `a <- hms("07:4:00")` vs `b <- hms("07:04:00")` vs `c <- hms("07:40:00")`. Both b and c cannot equal a. Further, I believe there's a fair assumption that users aren't meaning .04 of a minute when inputting `hm(7.04)`. TL;DR times are hard.

Comment: The problem I'm dealing with is times being listed as character string so I have the character string "740" which is meant to mean 7:40am so I did a 740/100 to convert to 7.4 and then used the hm() function on it and  that's when trouble ensued.  I understand that I could change "740" to something with colons which would solve my problem, I'm just curious why hm(7.4) and hm(7..04) both read as 7H 4M 0S.  It's seems pretty clear that using decimal points is not the way to go with changing characters to times.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: I emailed the devs and this is the response: "`hm` is a parser and operates on strings. Thus 7.4 is converted to string first which is "7.4". Same for 7.40."

Comment: Thanks for looking into" this.  So hm("7.4") returns 7H 4M 0S  and hm("7.40") returns 7H 40M 0S which I still find a little odd but I know how to handle this now and I have some insight into what's happening.